# Как добавить значения в Application.Current.Properties на этапе сборки?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Я пишу приложение на Xamarin.Forms, и некоторые значения, которые я получаю из Application.Current.Properties должны там быть уже на первом запуске, иначе приложение просто работать не сможет.

Есть ли возможность добавить туда значения во время сборки проекта?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.